# iOS Loading overlay does not cover the whole screen

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to display an overlay during an auto login HTTP call.
I've found [this code](https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message), which seems outdated somehow, but found nothing more recent.

Anyway, the Overlay is showing but not covering the whole screen as expected.

The calling code is this:

**AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching**

```
var avc = new AutoLoginViewController();
var navController = new UINavigationController(avc);
```

**AutoLoginViewController.ViewDidLoad**

```
var bounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;

// show the loading overlay on the UI thread using the correct orientation sizing
loadPop = new LoadingOverlay(bounds, NSBundle.MainBundle.GetLocalizedString("connecting"));
View.Add(loadPop);
```

But the result is the following:

[image: LoadOverlay incorrect size]

If I set a breakpoint in the LoadingOverlay constructor, I can see that the screen bounds (iPhone 6) are fine:

> {{X=0,Y=0,Width=375,Height=667}}

```
public class LoadingOverlay : UIView
{
    public LoadingOverlay(CGRect frame, string text) : base(frame)
    {
       // configurable bits
       BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
       Alpha = 0.75f;
       AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleDimensions;
       ...
    }
}
```

Clearly the UIView width is incorrect.

Because we're in 2020, maybe there is another way.

Any help appreciated.

---

EDIT: The app breaks on iPhone 8 iOS 13.3 simulator, So I can't say if this is tied to a particular screen size (1x in my case).

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use this solution? If not how about using https://github.com/redth-org/BTProgressHUD ? If you are okay with it I can add examples!

Comment: I'm okay with it, but for the sake of the question, I'd like to learn why the solution I'm using behaves like this.

Comment: Your code works fine in my project, so you could share a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Did you use an iPhone 6?

Comment: You could check my answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause :

It seems that you didn't set the **LaunchImage** , So whether on  a simulator or real device , the value of bounds is a static value .

Solution:

The easiest way is set the size of overlay as bounds of View .

```
var bounds = View.Bounds;
```

Or you could set all size of LaunchImage of different screen .